# Is it possible to run Slim client in Fitnesse server VM

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

We want to start the Slim client in the same virtual machine as the Fitnesse server. Is this possible?

I found only options for other ports or remote slim servers.

regards
Andreas

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this?  There may be another way to solve your issue.

Comment: In our enviroment we have a 1:1 ratio from slim clients to fitnesse servers. So we see no benefit in running different processes.

Another (probably) solvable reason was, that we had communication problems between slim client and fitnesse server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `&debug` to your suite or test URL (when the test is triggered).

See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices

So for instance http://localhost:9090/HsacExamples.SlimTests.UtilityFixtures.CompareFixtureTest?test&debug

But please note you must make sure your fixture classes are on the wiki's classpath. Any `!path` lines are ignored.